# How to generate a unique id in VB.NET with Access database?

Tags: vb.net

I want to generate a unique id to my employee id textbox and save it to my database in Access.

I tried this, but when I build the code, I see no errors and it still doesn't work.

```
Public Shared Function GetUniqueKey(ByVal maxSize As Integer) As String
    Dim chars As Char() = New Char(61) {}
    chars = "123456789".ToCharArray()
    Dim data As Byte() = New Byte(0) {}
    Dim crypto As New RNGCryptoServiceProvider()
    crypto.GetNonZeroBytes(data)
    data = New Byte(maxSize - 1) {}
    crypto.GetNonZeroBytes(data)
    Dim result As New StringBuilder(maxSize)
    For Each b As Byte In data
        result.Append(chars(b Mod (chars.Length)))
    Next
    Return result.ToString()
End Function

Public Sub AutoGenerate()
    EmployeeID.Text = "E-00" & GetUniqueKey(6)
End Sub

Private Sub New1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles new1.Click
    AutoGenerate()
    Reset()
End Sub
```

Comment: *it still doesn't work* - how does it not work? Does it return empty? Null? Does a chicken jump out of the screen? What?

Comment: yes it returns empty

Comment: It is the job of the database to "generate" unique Ids.  Even using a crypto generator you cant guarantee that the code (yours is leaking; and there is an easier way to convert the bytes to numbers/numberals) will create a unique one (random does not mean unique). Dont try to encode info into the IDs.  If you need an emplpyee *number* like `E-0012345` that is something much different than a unique identifier (Id)

Comment: so what do i do ... what is that simple thing